# How can I extract date from epoch time in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

1. I have date stored in `Epoch Time` and I want to extract
   `Date` from it. I tried the code below and I get `null` as output.

   ```
   date_add( (timestamp( Hp.ASSIGN_TIME)), 1970-01-01,"second" ) as Extracted_date_Epoch
   ```

   Ex time format(1424184621000000)
2. One more question. The code below give me days correctly but not business days, it gives all days,
   is it possible to get just business days betweeen two times stored in Epoch time?

   ```
   INTEGER(((Hp.ASSIGN_TIME - Hp.ARRIVAL_TIME) / 1000000) / 86400) as Days
   ```

Answer (score 65):

BigQuery offers two SQL modes. The original answer was based on **Legacy Mode**, but then I decided to update the answer by adding **Standard Mode** alternatives.

## Legacy Mode

To convert `timestamp` to `date` you can use [BigQuery date/time functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#datetimefunctions):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(1424184621000000)         # 2015-02-17 14:50:21 UTC    
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1230219000000000)  # 2008-12-25 15:30:00 UTC
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1230219000000)     # 2008-12-25 15:30:00 UTC
SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP(1424184621000000))   # 2015-02-17 
SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP('2015-02-17'))       # 2015-02-17 
SELECT INTEGER(TIMESTAMP('2015-02-17'))    # 1424131200000000
```

To calculate number of days between two dates (For example between 6/1/15 to 6/20/15), you can do this:

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP('2015-06-20'), TIMESTAMP('2015-06-01')) + 1)
```

And finally to calculate business days, you can use following:

```
SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP('2015-06-20'), TIMESTAMP('2015-06-01')) + 1)
  -(INTEGER((DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP('2015-06-20'), TIMESTAMP('2015-06-01')) + 1) / 7) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(TIMESTAMP('2015-06-01')) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(TIMESTAMP('2015-06-20')) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

This is simple business days calculation with considering Sat and Sun as weekends and not involving any holidays.

## Standard Mode

Here are some sample functions you can use for dealing with `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE`.

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(1230219000)       -- 2008-12-25 15:30:00 UTC
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(1230219000000)     -- 2008-12-25 15:30:00 UTC
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1230219000000000)  -- 2008-12-25 15:30:00 UTC

SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(1230219000)) -- 2008-12-25
SELECT CAST('2008-12-25' AS DATE)          -- 2008-12-25
SELECT DATE('2008-12-25', 'UTC')           -- 2008-12-25
```

For calculating days between two dates:

```sql
SELECT DATE_DIFF(DATE('2015-06-20'), DATE('2015-06-01'), DAY)
```

And finally calculate simple business days like above:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE_DIFF(DATE('2015-06-20'), DATE('2015-06-01'), DAY)
  - DIV(DATE_DIFF(DATE('2015-06-20'), DATE('2015-06-01'), DAY),7)*2
  - IF(EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DATE('2015-06-01'))=1,1,0)
  - IF(EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DATE('2015-06-20'))=7,1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Qorbani. Brilliant. I was struggling with business days for last few days. Works like magic.

Comment: Qorbani i would love to mark it as answer. I don't know how, all I see is Answer your question. I don't see options to vote it or like it or mark it as answer. How can i do that?

Comment: This only works in legacy mode.
```No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP for argument types: INT64. Supported signatures: TIMESTAMP(STRING, [STRING]); TIMESTAMP(DATE, [STRING]); TIMESTAMP(DATETIME, [STRING]) at [1:8]```

Comment: If you're not using legacy mode, you'll need something like: TIMESTAMP_MICROS(<int epoch>).
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_micros

Comment: @CosminLehene Thanks for your comment. I just added the Standard SQL model as well.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using standardSQL dialect in BigQuery, this function does the conversion to human readable timestamp 
TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1424184621000000) --> 2015-02-17 14:50:21 UTC. 
Ref: 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp-string

Alternatively `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime)` for seconds, e.g. in Google Analytics.

Comment: TIMESTAMP_MICROS(visitStartTime*1000000) works great for GA data, thanks!

Comment: Alternatively `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(visitStartTime)` for GA

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Legacy SQL option, to answer question 1, 
given a column of UNIX epoch time in milliseconds, like 1524375336000,

I used 
`SELECT USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(Hp.ASSIGN_TIME * 1000) AS the_date FROM table;`

```
╔═══╦═══════════════╦═════════════════════════════╗
║   ║ ASSIGN_TIME   ║ the_date                    ║
╠═══╬═══════════════╬═════════════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 1524375336000 ║ 2018-04-22 05:35:36.000 UTC ║
╚═══╩═══════════════╩═════════════════════════════╝
```

> `USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(<expr>)` Converts a UNIX timestamp in microseconds to
>   a TIMESTAMP data type.
>
> **Example**:
>
> `SELECT USEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(1349053323000000);`

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#usec_to_timestamp