# BigQuery Timestamp to Ruby time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-bigquery

I have a table with a column timestamp in type TIMESTAMP in BigQuery. When I display it on my console, I can see timestamps as follows: 2015-10-19 21:25:35 UTC

I then query my table using the BigQuery API, and when I display the result of the query, I notice that this timestamp has been converted in some kind of very big integer like 1.445289935E9 in string format.

Any idea on how do I convert it back to normal time? something I can use in my ruby code?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684920/how-can-i-extract-date-from-epoch-time-in-bigquery-sql

Comment: still returns the same value as before even if changing the query to 'SELECT TIMESTAMP(created_at) FROM [table_name] LIMIT 1000'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time.at("1.468768144014E9".to_f)